# webm html5 videos lose connection with apache server

Tags: apache-2.2, php, streaming, video, html5

webm html5 videos that are played through a domain on my server sometimes lose connection. A video that is playing will start to buffer and then stop part of way through with that message "Video playback aborted due to a network error." displayed on the html5 video player. I am delivering the webm videos via a php script on an LAMP server. There doesn't seem to be any errors in the server logs. Is there any php.ini settings or httpd.conf that I need to set? I recently set 'Keep Alive" to "on" in httpd.conf could that be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 video is still in its infancy and, to put it mildly, is not well supported by browsers. Sometimes improvements can be gained by trying different video formats but in most cases the problem will be at the browser, not the server. Try to see if the is happening more frequently with particular browser and offer those an alternative fall-back method.

Comment: Ok thanks John, I'll try viewing in another browser/s over the next few days and see what happens.

Comment: the solution to this was add more ram to the server and use nginx for delivery